# Inversion in English

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

Is it correct to invert the subordinate sentence in English? For instance:

> When the time comes, so shall we reign
>   the land!

If it is correct, what is the rule? Or is it only in old English?

Comment: I am confused about what you are referring to.  Are you talking about the inverted verb-subject order in the second clause?

Comment: yes, the inverted verb-subject order.

Comment: But here the first clause is subordinate. The inverted one is the main clause.

Comment: ''Full inches seven??''
Is this an archaic inversion

Comment: This does not answer the question. And there is no inversion involved at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is an archaic construction (and not limited to subordinate clauses/sentences); one wouldn't use it today except in dialog in a period piece.

Comment: Is `something wicked this way comes` also archaic?

Comment: Yes -- it's a quotation from Shakespeare's *Macbeth* (Act IV, Scene I).

Comment: "I like cinema." "So do I."

Comment: Also archaic, I'm afraid. (Even that meaning of the word *so* only holds in certain specific phrases.) Old forms hold on in frequently-used words and phrases even as the world changes around them. There are a few individual idiomatic phrases you just have to know -- like *so do I* and how to pluralize *ox*. There is no general rule of grammar to apply.

Comment: That meaning of *so* works in a surprising variety of places; see [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19394/is-so-a-pronoun). But it is definitely grammatically unique.

Comment: Subject-auxiliary inversion still happens in questions (*Do you like cinema?*) and [a few other places](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-auxiliary_inversion) (*Not since childhood had she eaten cotton candy*; *Only on Fridays does he go to the bar*.)

Comment: @Jason Orendorff: Indeed - there are plenty more situations were inversion happens - examples similar to "so" (Nor do I; As do I; Never have I...); questions (as you mention); fronted adverbials (In the house lives an old woman); comparatives ("Better still are the ones that follow") and so on. Inversion in general is far from archaic.