# Ouch! Are you Ok? I think so. What's the meaning of "so" in this sentence

Tags: meaning

> A: Ouch!
>
> B: Are you Ok?
>
> A:  I think so.

What's the meaning of "so"
in this last sentence

Comment: *So* is a pro-clause here. In that sentence it means *that I am ok*

Comment: '[so](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/so)': "in the way or manner indicated, described, or implied"

Comment: Ouch! Are you Ok? I think I am OK.  Using "so" allows me to avoid repeating the question.

Comment: See also [Is 'so' a pronoun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19394/is-so-a-pronoun)

Answer (score 1):

***So*** can replace *that* clauses for the sake of avoiding repetition:

> ***So** as **substitute***
>
> With some verbs, we often use ***so*** *instead of repeating an object clause*, especially in short answers:
>
> A:
> Will Megan be at the meeting today?
>
> B:
> *I think **so**.* (I think ***Megan will be at the meeting today***.)

([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/so))

Comment: Yes, **so** does that job because it points to **that** in a way as to indicate **that thing** or **like that**.

Comment: can we delete "so" in this sentence?

Comment: Without "so", _I think_ does not make sense as an answer.

Comment: @fev Some people might say "I think . . ." with emphasis on the second word, which trails off. (Perhaps "so" is understood in the trailing off part.)